# Sorting 2D array of chars C++

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I have a 2d array of chars where in each row I store a name... such as this:

```
J O H N
P E T E R
S T E P H E N
A R N O L D
J A C K
```

How should I go about sorting the array so that I end up with

```
A R N O L D
J A C K
J O H N
P E T E R
S T E P H E N
```

These is a 2d array of chars..... no strings or char points.....

Comment: What is the big difference between an array of strings and an array of chars? Sorting algorithms should work on this as well. Just that instead of swapping two string's positions you shuffle the array. Or pointers.

Comment: Ok, someone has to say it.  Do not store strings this way.  It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MAX_NAME 8

char names[][MAX_NAME] = {"JOHN", "PETER", "STEPHEN", "ARNOLD", "JACK"};
 // strcmp is really (int (*)(const char *, const char *)), so we cast.
qsort(names, sizeof(names) / MAX_NAME, MAX_NAME, 
  (int (*)(const void *, const void *)) strcmp);
```

Note that this is probably not a bubble sort.

Comment: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(const char*, const char*)throw ()’ to ‘int (*)(const void*, const void*)’|

Comment: I added a cast, which should resolve that error.  Basically, strcmp takes `const char*`, while qsort expects a function that takes `const void*`.

Comment: I get no errors now, but it's doing something bc when I print the array nothing gets printed. but before calling this method everything gets printed just fine

Comment: I made a simple [working demo](http://codepad.org/Cdogcl6R).  It shows it printing before and after.

Comment: yeah but that's an array of char pointers..... I have a 2d array of char so that's really not working.

Comment: No it's not.  It's a two-dimensional array, 5 rows by 8 columns.  Thomas's is a array of char pointers.  Maybe you should post the way your array is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bubble sort - point number 1.

Point number two:

Compare the first character of each sub array (i.e. array[x][0]) if it needs to be shifted then shift *all* characters in sub-array x using a while loop...or by saving the sub-array and shifting it like that...

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support copying or comparing C-style arrays, but it does support such operations on very thinly-wrapped C-style arrays. Try `boost::array`, which is the same as `tr1::array` and `std::array` in C++0x.

Or, roll your own:

```
#include <algorithm>

template< class T, size_t s >
struct array {
    T arr[s]; // public data, no destructor, inheritance, virtuals, etc
              // => type is aggregate
    operator T const *() const { return arr; }
    operator T *() { return arr; } // as close as we can get to array emulation

    friend bool operator< ( array const &l, array const &r )
        { return std::lexicographical_compare( l, l+s, r, r+s ); }
};

array< char, 10 > names[] // aggregate initialization — this is standard C++
    = { "JOHN", "PETER", "ARNOLD", "JACK" };

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
sort( names, names + sizeof names / sizeof *names );

for ( array<char,10> *s = names; s != names + sizeof names/sizeof*names; ++ s )
    cerr << *s << endl;
}
```

If your compiler doesn't insanely add padding to the above structure, you can safely `reinterpret_cast` a C-style array an an `array`:

```
template< class T, size_t s >
array< T, s > &wrap_arr( T (&a)[s] ) {
    return reinterpret_cast< array<T,s> & >( a );

        // make sure the compiler isn't really wacky...
        // I would call this optional:
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof( T[s] ) == sizeof( array<T,s> ) );
}

char names_c[][10] // or whatever C input from wherever
    = { "JOHN", "PETER", "ARNOLD", "JACK" };

array<char, 10> *names = &wrap_arr( names_c[0] );
```